# How do I make my discord bot only read content in a certain channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need help making my discord bot only read messages in a certain channel

So let's say you put !+!Verify in the verification channel I want it to verify you

But lets say you put it in the general channel I want it to not verify you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the channel ID with [channel.id](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=id) and if you get the channel from a message (`message.channel.id`) you can use it in an if statement to filter channels

```js
// client.on etc...

if (message.channel.id === 'CHANNEL-ID') {
    // When it is in the right channel
}
```